# Using Sql Server, How can I query elements in a json formatted column?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, arraylist

I have a table in my database that looks like this.

| manager id | employee info |
| --- | --- |
| 123567890123 | [{'emp_name':'ash','emp_id':'123'},{{'emp_name':'brad','emp_id':'234'}] |
| 235678901234 | [{'emp_name':'sarah','emp_id':'345'},{{'emp_name':'ryan','emp_id':'456'}] |

I want to sql server to query and  get each emp_name and emp_id for each manager
Below is my desired result.
I am using MS SQL Server 17

| manager id | emp_name | emp_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123567890123 | ash | 123 |
| 123567890123 | brad | 234 |
| 235678901234 | sarah | 345 |
| 235678901234 | ryan | 456 |

Comment: what your sql server version : `select @@version`

Comment: MS SQL Server 2017

Comment: Shredding this once when you load it is going to be a lot cheaper than shredding it every time you read it.

Comment: The desired result is how it should be stored in the first place.

Comment: i did not create the table. I just have to fix it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

With that you can do something like:

```
SELECT ManagerId,
  JSON_VALUE(`employee info`, '$.emp_name') AS emp_name,
  JSON_VALUE(`employee info`, '$.emp_id') + AS emp_id
FROM Managers;
```

This is pseudo code. You will probably need to update it for your schema.

EDIT: Just because you *can* do it this way, doesn't necessarily mean you *should* do it this way. Whether or not to use this solution, of course depends on your problem.

Comment: when i tried that exactly the emp_name and emp_id fields are null

Comment: @AshalynnBriannDavis Yeah, you're going to have to play with it. I don't have your schema, data, or SQL Server 2017 to be able to debug it myself. I'll try to set up a test in 2019.

Comment: ok thanks let me know if you think of anything

Answer (score 0):

…[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2b4b6024e0b17f5aceaff6ce0f2d2d03)…

```
select *
from
(
values(123567890123, N'[{"emp_name":"ash","emp_id":"123"},{"emp_name":"brad","emp_id":"2349"}]')
) as thetable([manager id], [employee info])
cross apply openjson(thetable.[employee info])
with
(
emp_name nvarchar(20),
emp_id nvarchar(20)
) as e;
```

Comment: I have more columns than those two. I was just showing how the table is formatted